# PCA-SIFT in Java

Tags: java, pca, sift

Does anybody have a source code or even just a pseudocode for PCA-SIFT in Java language?

I'm making a program which extracts SIFT features from images and then feeding those features from multiple images to an ELM but I'm having problems with the number of features since there are different number of features extracted per image.

That's why I'm trying to use PCA to get a specific number of features per image. But I don't understand how to use PCA with SIFT.

Answer (score 0):

It contains the source code : 
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~yke/pcasift/

Comment: The source code is not in java as requested in the question.